# Is there a git command to transform a non tracking branch in a tracking branch?

Tags: git, git-branch

I know that one can edit `.git/config` file to do this! I'm asking for a native `git` command to do this. The key point here is that the branch already exists (and maybe with new commits compared with the remote branch) so `git branch --tracking BRANCH_NAME REMOTE_BRANCH` gives an error.

Comment: git branch --set-upstream BRANCHNAME origin/BRANCHNAME ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try

```
--set-upstream BRANCHNAME origin/BRANCHNAME
```

?

Comment: Thanks to all! `--set-upstream BRANCHNAME origin/BRANCHNAME` is what I was looking for.

Comment: Sure, is that I can't do that inmidiately, I must wait a few minutes ;) SO rules.